# The producer/consumer problem - changing semaphores order

Tags: concurrency, semaphore, producer-consumer

Let's assume I have got a multi producers and a single consumer scenario.
The pseudo code for a producer is:

```
product = produce()
wait(empty)
wait(mutex)
array[in] = product
in = (in + 1) % n
signal(mutex)
signal(full)
```

The pseudo code for a consumer is:

```
wait(full)
product = array[out]
out = (out + 1) % n
signal(empty)
useProduct()
```

What would happen if I swap semaphores in the consumer i.e. signal(empty) before wait(full) ??
I have tried to implement this scenario in java but I can't really see any change.

Answer (score 0):

`wait(full)` is there to notify the consumer that there is something to consume. If you do not issue `wait(full)` first, the consumer can consume before a producer produced anything.

If you're testing this in Java, try starting the consumer before the producer, and let the producer wait a little bit before producing the first item to let the consumer "consume".